# Changing getPdf function

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to change the `getPdf` function to send orderid to `_Addfooter` to get the final tax amount. I created a module and added the function as it is to see if it's working but I'm getting below error when I tried to generate the invoice. I added `_drawTotal` function in my module but then started getting error for another function. I don't want to copy the whole file in my module.

```
Invalid method Vendor\InvoicePdf\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice::_drawTotal
```

I'm a newbie to Magento2 and PHP. Ideally I'm trying to remove Tax column for each item and then in notes section I'm trying to add the total tax value.

Below is the code from my module, please let me know what I'm missing.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\InvoicePdf\Model\Order\Pdf;

 use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Collection;

 class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
protected function _drawHeader(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
{
    /* Add table head */
    $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
    $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
    $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
    $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
    $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 15);
    $this->y -= 10;
    $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0, 0, 0));

    //columns headers
    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Products'), 'feed' => 35];

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('SKU'), 'feed' => 290, 'align' => 'right'];

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Qty'), 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Price'), 'feed' => 360, 'align' => 'right'];

    /*$lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Tax'), 'feed' => 495, 'align' => 'right'];*/

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Subtotal'), 'feed' => 565, 'align' => 'right'];

    $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 5];

    $this->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
    $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
    $this->y -= 20;
  }

   /**
     * Return PDF document
     *
     * @param array|Collection $invoices
     * @return \Zend_Pdf
     */
    public function getPdf($invoices = [])
    {
        $this->_beforeGetPdf();
        $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

        $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
        $this->_setPdf($pdf);
        $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
        $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
                $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
            }
            $page = $this->newPage();
            $order = $invoice->getOrder();
            
            $_SESSION['orderid'] = $order->getRealOrderId();
            /* Add image */
            $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add address */
            $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add head */
            $this->insertOrder(
                $page,
                $order,
                $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
                    self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    $order->getStoreId()
                )
            );
            /* Add document text and number */
            $this->insertDocumentNumber($page, __('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId());
            /* Add table */
            $this->_drawHeader($page);
            /* Add body */
            foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                /* Draw item */
                $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                $page = end($pdf->pages);
            }
            /* Add totals */
            $this->_drawTotal($page);
            $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                $this->_localeResolver->revert();
            }
        }
        
            $this->_Addfooter($page,$this->getOrderNote($order));

        $this->_afterGetPdf();
        return $pdf;
    }
    
  /**
     * Set font as regular
     *
     * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
     * @param int $size
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
     */
    protected function _setFontRegular($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/Font/DejaVuSans.ttf')
        );
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }

    /**
     * Set font as bold
     *
     * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
     * @param int $size
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
     */
    protected function _setFontBold($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/Font/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf')
        );
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }

    /**
     * Set font as italic
     *
     * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page $object
     * @param int $size
     * @return \Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font
     */
    protected function _setFontItalic($object, $size = 7)
    {
        $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath(
            $this->_rootDirectory->getAbsolutePath('lib/internal/Font/DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf')
        );
        $object->setFont($font, $size);
        return $font;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your _drawTotal function defined?

Comment: It exists in the original class. Within my module I extended the class so it should bring the function along from base function.

Comment: Which Magento version you used? Because I've checked, there is no function named _drawTotal.

Comment: Thanks James for checking, we have magento 2.2.6. If this function doesnt exists by default then I believe this is something the previous developer has hacked the original module :-(